# When I control uistatusbar to display or hide, The view will shake

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

Copy `IOS` photo gallery style, but when I control `uistatusbar` to display or hide, the view will shake to up and down.

```
if (isDisplayNav) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        isDisplayNav = NO;
}else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        isDisplayNav = YES;
}
```

=========================answer=======================

I find the answer, you can insert [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES] in viewDidLoad method, the statusbar's height will not include in the viewController